# Read file data from Azure Storage FileShare

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, storage-file-share

I am trying to read data from the files (json files) that exists in my Azure Storage's FileShare. I don't want to download the file and instead just read and get the data. The following command downloads the file for me instead of reading and storing the data in a variable. Please help.

```
$fileContents = Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $filePath -Context (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name "name").Context -OutVariable fileContents
```

How can I read the data and potentially post files in the filshare as well? I have been following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragefilecontent?view=azps-9.2.0) but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*Initially I tried with below commands to read the file from azure-file share with downloading it worked.*

**Commands:**

```
$accountName = "venkat123"
$accountKey = "<storage account key >"
$fileshareName = "fileshare1"
$Name = "directory1/file.json"
$content="<downloaded path\file.json>"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -StorageAccountKey $accountKey

Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $fileShareName -Path $Name -Destination "file.json" -Context $ctx
Get-content -path $content
```

**Console:**

[image]

As workaround, if you need to read the files in azure file share without downloading you can use below python code.

**Code:**

```
from  azure.storage.file  import  FileService

storageAccount='venkat123'
accountKey='xxxxxxx'
file_service = FileService(account_name=storageAccount, account_key=accountKey)

share_name="fileshare1"

directory_name="directory1"

file_name="file.json"

file = file_service.get_file_to_text(share_name, directory_name, file_name)

print(file.content)
```

**Console:**
[image]